# SSH Bash script issues with if statement

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to learn how to write Bash scripts. I have this script to update my servers through ssh. I'm trying to add a check and a conditional to determine if the OS uses Yum or Apt then it will run the appropriate update commands. The if else statement seems to be wrong but I'm not sure how to correct this.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME="root"
HOSTS="host1 host2 host3"
apt_run="apt update && apt -y upgrade"
yum_run="yum check-update && yum -y update"

for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
    ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} 
    find_os=$( command -v yum || command -v apt-get ) || echo "Neither 
    yum nor apt-get found"
    if [[ $find_os='yum' ]]
       then
       "${yum_run}"
    else
       "${apt_run}"
    fi

done
```

Comment: What are the scripts after `"Neither yum nor $`? Seems its too long and cut off by an editor.

Comment: Spaces are part of shell syntax. You want `[[ $find_os == 'yum' ]]` or probably more accurately (because `command -v yum` on my workstations returns `/usr/bin/yum`): `[[ "${find_os##*/}" == yum ]]`

Comment: Also of note: you are running those commands locally, not over ssh. Feed the commands to be ran remotely to stdin via a heredoc.

Comment: `ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME}  <there is no command here>`. The syntax is `user@host`...

Comment: Storing commands in variables (like `apt_run` and `yum_run`) has severe problems (see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). Using it with `ssh` might actually work, because the oddities of `ssh` command parsing might cancel out those of variable expansion... sort of. Maybe. But IMO it's better to avoid the additional source of confusion, and just use commands directly wherever possible.

Comment: `ssh` is starting an interactive shell on the remote host. Until that shell exits, your script blocks; `find_os=$(...)` will execute *locally* once that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my script for my virtual machines.

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=(
  leap151 kali ubuntu omv
)

for hostname in "${hosts[@]}"; do
ssh -t root@"$hostname" << 'EOF'
  if type -P zypper >/dev/null; then
    command zypper ref && command zypper up
   elif type -P apt-get >/dev/null; then
     command apt-get update && command apt-get upgrade
  else
    echo 'Neither zypper nor apt found!' >&2
    exit 127
  fi
EOF
done
```

Use an array for the host. Since you're using bash the builtin `type` is fine just for searching the executable within your PATH. See `help type` for more info. Use the `-t` option in ssh also use a heredoc just what I have/did. The exit 127 is what the shell would exit if there are no executable see `man 1p exit`.

Comment: What are the functions for? They're defined in the local shell, so they won't be available to the remote shells running over ssh (and you don't seem to use them at all -- just the literal commands, which *will* work fine).

Comment: `command apt-get update && apt-get` - why do you use `command` at all, and why do you use it with the first, but not with the second command?

Comment: yeah, need the command with both apt-get, I will update the script.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the function got mixed up on my dev branch. Ill remove them.